# In vimscript using current word as parameter in if statement

Tags: vim

I would like to do something like this

```
if exists(expand('<cword>'))
  inoremap ( (<esc>g_i)<left>
else
  inoremap ( ()<left>
endif
```

The logic behind this is that if there is something under my curser, surround that with the parenthesis, otherwise just create a closed parenthesis.

The if does not currently recognize the element under the cursor.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I think this is inside out.  Instead of a few lines (perhaps part of a function) that conditionally define an `:inoremap`, don't you want an `:inoremap` that calls a function that has conditional code?  Before trying to write your complete function, check interactively:  `:echo expand('<cword>')` and `:exists(expand('<cword>'))` and so on.  I think the first will do what you want, not the second.  Perhaps you want `strlen()` instead of `exists()`.

Comment: This was very helpful strlen() was what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a mapping react to the current conditions *when it is invoked*, you cannot redefine the mapping itself. Instead you have to make the *right-hand side* of the mapping react to the conditions. This is done easiest with a `:help :map-expr`, like this:

```
:inoremap <expr> ( (empty(expand('<cword>')) ? '()<Left>' : '(<Esc>g_i)<Left>')
```

<sup>Note that I just translated your example, I didn't check that it makes sense or works as expected.</sup>